# Show that Frobenius endomorphism on supersingular curves is an integer

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I was working my way through the Exercises in the Book [Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography](http://koclab.cs.ucsb.edu/teaching/ecc/eccPapers/Washington-ch04.pdf) by L. Washington.
Exercise 4.12 tells us to:

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $E$ be a supersingular elliptic curve over the finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$. Let $\phi_p$ be the Frobenius endomorphism. Show that some power of $\phi_p$ is an integer. (Note: This is easy when $p \geq 5$. The cases $p = 2,3$ can be done by a case-bye-case calculation.)

My solution is:

For $p \geq 5$ we have if $E$ is supersingular then $a = 0$ and since $\phi_p^2 -a\phi_p + p = 0$ we have $\phi_p^2 = -p$

For $p = 2$ since $ a\equiv 0$ mod 2, with Hasse we have that $a = \{-2,0,2\}$ and since $\phi_p$ is the identity on $\mathbf{F}_p$ we get that $\phi_p^2 = \{0,-2,-4\}$.

Analog for $p=3$

My first question: Is this argumentation correct?

Second question: Since if $p$ is a prime number and $\phi_p = (x^p, y^p)$ with little Fermat we have $(x^p, y^p) = (x,y)$. Does that mean we can find for any elliptic curve an integer, such that $\phi_p^2$ is an integer or did i forget something?

Third question: Since $\phi_p$ is the identity on $\mathbf{F}_p$ and the question asked to show that the power of $\phi_p$ is an integer, could i just say $\phi_p^1 = 1$ and be done?

Link to similar question: [Show that $\phi_p^2 = -p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097519/show-that-phi2-p-p?rq=1)

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself between the action of the frobenius on the points of the Elliptic curve vs the action on $\mathbb F_p$. When you say that $\phi_p^2 = -p$ on $E$, what you mean is that for a point $(x,y)$ on $E$, $(x^{p^2},y^{p^2})$ is the same as multiplying by $-p$ (in the group law). Note that $x,y$ do not need to be in $\mathbb F_p$, they could be in the any two numbers in the algebraic closure. So in particular, $x^p \neq x$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i revisited the definition on Frobenius endomorphism and saw that it is defined over the algebraic closure of $ \overline{ \mathbf{F} }_p$. We only have $\phi_p(x,y) = (x,y) $ iff. $(x,y) \in \mathbf{F}_p$. Can you tell me what would be correct way to show for $p=2$ that $\phi_p$ is an integer, if i cant use that $a\phi_p = a$?

Comment: You are almost there for $p = 2$, you know that the quadratic equation the Frobenius satisfies looks like $x^2 \pm 2x + 2 = 0$ (or $a_2 = 0$ and you are already done). Prove that no matter what the sign in the middle is, the roots of that equation, raised to some power, is an integer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just enumerate the finitely many (maybe just 1?) supersingular curves in char 2, 3 and compute the frobenius explicitly and prove it

Comment: Thank you for the hints, for the quadratic equation i was able to show that for p=2, the 4th power is equal to the integer -4 and for p=3 the 6th power is equal to the integer -27. For the Alternative, since supersingularity is a property over the algebraic close field, i only have to show that for every specific j-invariante class of elliptic curves that this property holds. With a bit of calculation i see that for p=2 only the class of j-inv = 0 is supersingular and for p=3 only the class of j-inv = 0 is supersingular. Take one arbitrary EC from the class and show the property.

Comment: I have one question remaining, why can we take the equation $\phi_p^2 \pm 2 \phi_p +2 = 0$ and transform it to a quadratic equation of form $x^2 \pm 2x +2 = 0$? Since the numbers in the first equation represent multiplication maps on a elliptic curve, and during the solution of the second equation a take a sqrt. But what would it mean to take the square root of a multiplication map?

Comment: Good question, it's not really like taking a square root. Rather, we know that $\phi$ is just some algebraic thing whose first and second powers satisfy that equation. The square root thing is just an easy way to keep track of it. If you like, you could write $\phi_p^4 = (\phi_p^2)^2 = (2\phi_p \pm 2)^2$, expand using algebra and replace the $\phi_p^2$ terms again using the quadratic equation.